ambiguity inside solana's GetAccountInfo rpc
I'm confused while using rpc getAccountInfo because the value of the answer will always be null when the Solana balance is 0. This happens even when the address is new and the account has multiple tokens but the balance is 0. Aside from that, I'd like to know if entering a smart contract with a balance of 0 will result in a null return. Is it conceivable for a smart contract to have a balance of 0? Do you have an example?
